# Template parameter in classes

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T, typename X, typename Y>
class multipler{
public:
 mutiplier(X xi, Y yi):x(xi),y(yi){}
 T operator ()(T t){
  return (x(t) * y(t))
 }

private:
 X x;
 Y y;

}


multiplier(obj1, obj2); //temp object
```

Must all template parameters be known before an temporary object of a template class is created?
T is not known till something calls () on multiplier(obj1, obj2)
e.g multiplier(obj1, obj2)(5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to create an object, the exact type of the object to create must be known. What do you think should be the supposed meaning of "creating an object of a partially known type"!? In your particular case, it would appear that what you actually want is to only have `X` and `Y` be type parameters of the class and then have a function call operator for this type that can take any `T` as an argument. To achieve this, you would simply make the function call operator itself a template:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
class multiplier {
public:
  multiplier(X xi, Y yi) : x(xi), y(yi) {}

  template <typename T>
  T operator ()(T t) {
    return x(t) * y(t);
  }

private:
  X x;
  Y y;
};


multiplier(obj1, obj2)(some_T); // temp object, called with some T
```

Comment: I want to pass this temporary object into a function.
for example:
F f;
G g;
integrator(multiplier(f,g), 1, 0)
Integrator calls multiplier(f,g)(1) and multiplier(f,g)(0), not the whole computation obviously but it makes these calls.
Will your example work for this? Thanks

Comment: @LuckyBlue That depends a lot on the specifics. What's the signature of this `integrator()`? Is it a function or a function template, or an object? If it's not a template, it will be hard to pass an object of arbitrary type as an argument there. If there is a specific example that you need to get to work then you should mention this in you question. You should still be able to edit your question and add more context…

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
class multipler{
public:
  mutiplier(X xi, Y yi):x(xi),y(yi){}
  template<class T>
  T operator ()(T t){
    return (x(t) * y(t))
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't really give an answer to the question.

Comment: @alonso Itbsolves the concrete problem.  It does lack the word "yes"